# Nim multiplication inverse

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

We have
$$\operatorname{mex} S=\min \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \notin S\},a \oplus b=\operatorname{mex}\{a' \oplus b ; a \oplus b', \forall a', b'\in \mathbb{N}: a'<a, b'<b\},$$
and
$$a \otimes b=\operatorname{mex}\{(a' \oplus b) \oplus (a \otimes b') \oplus (a' \otimes b') \mid a',b' \in \mathbb{N}, a'<a, b'<b\}.$$
Let $c \in \mathbb{N}^*$, prove that there exists a unique number $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c \otimes d = 1$.

The operation $\otimes$ is called the nim multiplication. I have proven its commutative, associative, and distributive properties with addition. I am currently proving its existence of an inverse. In the book "On Numbers and Games" by John H. Conway, on page 56, there is a mention of the formula for the inverse, but there is no mention of the proof, stating similarly to chapter 1. I have revisited chapter 1 but gained no insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Conway's convention, instead of using $\oplus, \otimes$, and $\oslash$ for nimber operations, I will just use the ordinary $+,\cdot,$ and $\frac{x}y$.

We will need to use the fact that nimber multiplication has no zero divisors. That is, if $a$ and $b$ are nonzero  nimbers, then $ab\neq 0$. To see this, note that $ab\neq a'b+ab'+a'b'$ for all $a'<a$ and $b'<b$, and take $a'=b'=0$.

---

In *ONAG*, Conway gives the following inductive definition for the nim multiplicative inverse. When $x\neq 0$ is a nimber,
$$
\frac1x=\text{mex }(Y),\text{ where }\\ Y=\left\{0,\frac{1+(x+x')\cdot y'}{x'} \mid 1\le x'<x ,y'\in Y\right\}
$$
The way that I wrote it, $Y$ is circularly defined in terms of itself. To be rigorous, define a sequence of sets $Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ inductively as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
Y_0&=\{0\}\\
Y_{n+1}&=\left\{\frac{1+(x+x')\cdot y'}{x'} \mid 1\le x'<x,y'\in Y_n\right\} \qquad (n\ge 0)
\end{align}
$$
We then define $Y=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty Y_n$.

> **Lemma:** For all $y'\in Y$, $xy'\neq 1$.

*Proof:* If $y'=0$, then obviously $xy'=0\neq 1$. Otherwise, since $y'\in Y_n$ for some $n\ge 1$, then we know that $$y'=\frac{1+(x+x')y''}{x'}$$ for some $x'<x$ and some $y''\in Y_{n-1}$. We can rewrite this equation as
$$
(1+xy')=(1+xy'')\cdot (x+x')\cdot \frac1{x'}
$$
Now, by induction on $n$, we know that $xy''\neq 1$, so that $1+xy''\neq 0$. Since $x'<x$, we have $x'+x\neq 0$. Finally, applying the formula for $\frac1x$ inductively to $x'$, we know that $0$ is an excludant for $\frac1{x'}$, so $\frac1{x'}\neq 0$. All three factors are nonzero, so the fact that nimber multiplication has no zero divisors implies that $1+x'y\neq 0$, so $xy'\neq 1$.

$\tag*{$\square$}$

> **Theorem:** Letting $y=\operatorname{mex} Y$, we have $xy=1$.

*Proof:* Recalling that $$xy=\operatorname{mex}P, \text{ where }P=\{x'y+xy'+x'y'\mid x'<x, y'<y\},$$ we just need to show $\operatorname{mex} P=1$, which is equivalent to $0\in P$ and $1\notin P$. To see that $0\in P$, simply take $x'=0$ and $y'=0$ in the definition of $P$.

We must show $xy'+x'y+x'y'\neq 1$ for all $x'<x$ and $y'<y$. In the case where $x'=0$, this is equivalent to showing $xy'\neq 1$ for all $y' < y$, which was handled by the Lemma. From now on, assume $x'\neq 0$. In this case, we can write
$$
x'y+xy'+x'y'=1+x'y+x'\cdot \frac{1+(x+x')y'}{x'}
$$
Say that $y'\in Y_n$. Letting  $y''=\frac{1+(x+x')y'}{x'}$, by definition we have $y''\in Y_{n+1}$. The above becomes
$$
x'y+xy'+x'y'=1+x'y + x'\cdot y''=1+x'(y+y'')
$$
Now, since $y=\operatorname{mex} Y$ and $y''\in Y$, it follows $y\neq y''$, which implies that $y+y''\neq 0$. Since there are no zero-divisors, and since $x'\neq 0$, we conclude $1+x'(y+y'')\neq 1$. This proves that $x'y+xy'+x'y'\neq 1$ for all $x'<x$ and $y'<y$, as required.

$\tag*{$\square$}$

Comment: Thank you! 
May I ask, if $Y=\mathbb{N}$, does the mex $Y$ exist?

Comment: Great question; the mex of $\mathbb N$ is infinity! Specifically, it is $\omega$, the first infinite [ordinal number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). All of nimber math can be extended to the ordinals, using the same mex definitions. Fun fact: it turns out that the number cube root of two is equal to $\omega$.

Comment: I am rewriting the theory of nim sum and product with natural numbers (I don't aim to construct nimbers, but want to preserve the original construction method).

+ According to that, is $\operatorname{mex} \mathbb{N}=- \infty$ correct? Because the definition of $\operatorname{mex} S$ is the smallest non-negative integer not in $S$. Please forgive my ignorance in this matter.
+ In the proof above (which I found very easy to understand), $\operatorname{mex} Y:=y$ so if $Y= \mathbb{N}$ then using $y$ as above is acceptable, right?

Thank you very much!

Comment: edit: $\operatorname{mex} \mathbb{N}=+\infty$

Comment: Hmm, if you aim to build the theory of nimber math on the natural numbers, I would avoid infinity, and say that mex is only well-defined for sets whose complement is nonempty, because adding $\infty$ into the mix makes things unnecessarily complex. This means that, for this proof, you would need to prove that $Y\neq\mathbb N$ for the construction to be well-defined. I can prove this, but the margin of this comment box is too narrow to contain the proof.

Comment: I've tried to prove $Y \neq \mathbb{N}$ but haven't succeeded. I've noticed that $Y_n$ is periodic, which implies $Y$ is finite (I tested some $Y$ corresponding to $x=2;3;4$ and observed that). Can you suggest a proof direction? (Please don't provide a detailed proof to keep it interesting) Thanks.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151490/nimber-math)